# How to migrate branched to a new repository without commit history?

Tags: git, repository, git-repo

I created a new git repository and want to migrate some branches to it.
However I don't want to migrate the commit history.
what I've done:

## 1  create new repository and use

```
git remote set-url origin XXXXX
to switch to the new repo.
```

## 2 I have a branch "test" with a long commit history.

I want to push it to new repo but I don't want these commit history.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just send the files and not the `.git` directory. So no git tracking history was shared.